# Allocating new node in Linked List using C++ reference parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

This code snippet is valid for creating new node at the begining.

```
void push(node **head_ref,int n_data){
   node *new_node= new(node);
   new_node->data=n_data;
   new_node->next=(*head_ref);
   *head_ref=new_node;
}
int main(){
   node *head=NULL;
   push(&head,data);
   return 0;
}
```

This is invalid but why?
What i am trying to do is create a reference parameter as mentioned in Herbert Schildt.

```
void push(node &(*head_ref),int n_data){
   node *new_node= new(node);
   new_node->data=n_data;
   new_node->next=head_ref;
   head_ref=new_node;
}
int main(){
   node *head=NULL;
   push(head,data);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `node &(*head_ref)` makes `head_ref` a *pointer* to a reference, not a reference to a pointer, which would be `node*& head_ref`.

Answer (score 0):

A Null-Pointer can't be a reference!
So in C++ there is the only way, to use a double pointer.

Using a Reference to a Null-Pointer could lead to undefined behavior, this means that you should avoid this.

Maybe boost::optional is what you need, but than you need some modifications.

But why are you not just using the std::list?